# CustomAttribute reflects html attribute MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

Hoping to find a way when in MVC5 a Custom attribute or preferable the RegularExpressionAttribute decorates a property in the model the html control will contain it as another attribute of the control. E.g.

```
class CoolModel {
   [CustomHtmlAttribute("hello")]
   public string CoolValue {get;set;} 
}
```

outputs...

```
<input type="text" customhtml="hello" />
```

Or something like that. So for the RegularExpressionAttribute the pattern attribute will be awesome.

```
class CoolModel {
   [RegularExpressionAttribute("/d")]
   public string CoolValue {get;set;} 
}
```

outputs...

```
<input type="text" pattern="/d" />
```

I need this output without enabling the Javascript unobtrusive option. So I'm thinking in a way to specify some attribute in the model that gets push down to the view. Not sure if the Data annotations provider could do this job. Not sure if a Helper could be extended to get this result.

Help is appreciated.

Comment: To achieve this you can just use the standard helpers and add html attributes `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SomeProperty, new { customhtml = "hello" })`. Doing it using custom data annotations will be much more complex

Comment: See [this link](http://aspadvice.com/blogs/kiran/archive/2009/11/29/Adding-html-attributes-support-for-Templates-_2D00_-ASP.Net-MVC-2.0-Beta_2D00_1.aspx)

Comment: Thanks both for the answers. @StephenMuecke I'm aware of that but I need to specify the attribute in the model for maintainability  purposes.

Comment: @artm I checked that link earlier and I wonder if there is another way to do it. Could you add a meta attribute that gets to be render in the view without doing that whole process?

Comment: In that case artm's link may be useful, although its a bit out of date and does rely on creating custom `EditorTemplates` which can be difficult to maintain across projects. The other alternative is to implement IMetadataAware to add the attributes to `metadata.AdditionalValues`, then create a set of custom html helpers that merge the attributes

Comment: You need to implement the whole thing if you want to add custom attributes to be displayed in views. Easier way is @StephenMuecke 's response. Depends how often you're going to use the attribute. If you need it on 50 model properties implement the attribute once, if you need it on 5 properties, add it inside the view like Stephen suggested.

Comment: @StephenMuecke - Yes, I discarded that solution earlier. Could you share an example of your suggestion please?

Comment: @StephenMuecke That's true, IMetadataAware is a better way of doing it, link is bit old. Plenty of IMetadataAware examples on the internet.

Comment: @artm - Yes, we will use this approach in an extensive way. Big big forms.. :(

Comment: I'll post a simple example shortly

Comment: @StephenMuecke - Can I add metadata.AdditionalValues in the Data annotations provider? I'm saying this because I already have this mechanism implemented. However the question remains.. By adding this, will the new attributes be reflected when the view is rendered or I need to write a custom html helper anyways?

Comment: Adding the values to `AdditionalValues` is not enough. You will need to use custom helpers or use custom `EditorTemplates` in order to render the values in the view

Comment: That's what I thought...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If using the standard helpers with the overload to add html attributes is not acceptable, then you can create an attribute implements `IMetadataAware` that adds properties to `metadata.AdditionalValues` which can then be used in custom html helpers. A simple example might be

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class CustomHtmlAttribute : Attribute, IMetadataAware
{
  public static string ValueKey
  {
    get { return "Value"; }
  }
  public string Value { get; set; }
  public void OnMetadataCreated(ModelMetadata metadata)
  {
    if (Value != null)
    {
      metadata.AdditionalValues[ValueKey] = Value;
    }
  }
}
```

and to create a helper to render a textbox (only one overload shown here)

```
public static MvcHtmlString CustomHtmlTextBoxFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
{
  ModelMetadata metaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, helper.ViewData);
  object attributes = null;
  if (metaData.AdditionalValues.ContainsKey(ValueKey))
  {
    attributes = new { customhtml = (string)metaData.AdditionalValues[ValueKey] };
  }
  return InputExtensions.TextBoxFor(helper, expression, attributes);
}
```

and use it as

```
[CustomHtml(Value = "hello")]
public string CoolValue { get; set; }
```

and in the view

```
@Html.CustomHtmlTextBoxFor(m => m.CoolValue)
```

to make this a bit more flexible, you could add more properties to the attribute so you could apply it as

```
[CustomHtml(Value = "hello", Pattern="/d")]
public string CoolValue { get; set; }
```

and modify the helper to render all the html attributes you define.