# How change a view input class based on model data anotation in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, class, razor, model, data-annotations

Is possible to change the view input class based on a model annotation. for instance:

```
[required]
[class("phone-class")]
public string Phone {get; set;}
```

and it would output

```
<input name="Phone" class="phone-class" />
```

Comment: Only by creating your own `HtmlHelper` extension methods. Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26519493/customattribute-reflects-html-attribute-mvc5/26519946#26519946) for an example.