# Not including space or css class in MVC razor and simpfying code by using Expressions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

At times I need to have the css class for div to have values, at other times I don't want to have class attribute or it's properties

```
<div> 
<div class="highligh">
```

I have tried using a function as such

```
<div @GetCssClass(Model.IsThisPropertyHighlighted)>@Model.ThisProperty
```

but the problem is I  can either get

```
<div > or <div class="">
```

Neither of them is satisfactory,

of course I also get `<div class="highligh">` which is the only satisfactory case.

Comment: You can always write your own extension methods to generate the html (for example something like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26519493/customattribute-reflects-html-attribute-mvc5/26519946#26519946)) where you might have a `[ClassName("highlight")]` attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please avoid calling functions in razor view.

Instead create a property in the model and in your razor view you can simply specify.

```
<div class="@Model.NewProperty">
```

If `NewProperty` is null class attribute will not be rendered at all.

Comment: That is fantasic! I think I accept this as answer and move my second part of question to a separate question.

Comment: @Arjang glad it helps!