# MVC 5 Add 'data-' attribute with Custom Data Annotation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, metadata, data-annotations

I have an input text field, and I want to be able to restore the initial value after the user edits the text.
So, I would say to add a `data-{something}` attribute, for instance `data-init`, that will hold the initial value, so it can be restored later.

Result should look like:

```
<input type="text" val="Some value..." data-init="Some value..." />
```

Now, I know I can achieve this by using:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.InputText , new { data_init = Model.InputText })
```

But it's awful, and I have a lot of input fields with this behavior.

Also, I can't create a custom **HtmlHelper** because I have many input types with this behavior, it will be quite messy if I go this way...

So, what I think should be the practical solution is to use **Data Annotations**.

```
public class ExampleVM
{
    [HoldInitialValue]
    public string InputText { get; set; }
}
```

The `[HoldInitialValue]` attribute will be responsible to add the `data-init="{value}"` to the input tag. The {value} will be taken from the property's value, with also an option to override it.

So, how do I implement this behavior?

Thanks for the helpers.

Comment: By writing a custom HtmlHelper. Do you know how to?

Comment: @IvayloStoev - Yes I know, I rejected the HtmlHelper solution because I have many input types with this behavior, it will be quite messy if I go this way...

Comment: If you want to use data annotations like this someone has to evaluate them. This is usually a helper. I don't see any other meaningful extension point. Another option (not really the MVC way) is to do it from the client side and add the initial values when the html elements are rendered for the first time by using some javascript code and based for example on some common css class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you were to create a custom attribute, which would need to implement [MetadataAware](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.imetadataaware(v=vs.118).aspx) in order to add the value to the `AdditionalValues` property of [ModelMetadata](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelmetadata(v=vs.118).aspx), you still then need to create your own extension methods to read that value and add it to the `htmlAttributes`.

For an example of how to implement it, refer [CustomAttribute reflects html attribute MVC5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26519493/customattribute-reflects-html-attribute-mvc5/26519946#26519946).

However, that is unnecessary since HTML inputs already store the initial value. For a `<input>` (other than a checkbox) or `<textarea>` its `defaultValue`. For a `<input type="checkbox" />` its `defaultChecked` and for  `<select>` its `defaultSelected`.

So in the case of your `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.InputText)`, your could use for example

using javascript

```
var element = document.getElementById ("InputText");
var initialValue = elem.defaultValue;
// reset to initial value
element.value = initialValue;
```

or using jQuery

```
var element = $('#InputText');
var initialValue = element.prop('defaultValue');
// reset to initial value
element.val(initialValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one , using htmlAttributes as IDictionary

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.InputText , new Dictionary<string,object>()
               {
                   { "data-init", Model.InputText}
               })
```