# How to render ModelMetadata object using Html.Displar in Razor-engine in ASP.NET MVC app?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, razorengine, display-templates

I am trying to utilize the `DisplayTemplates` feature in razor-engine to automate rendering my display views.

I scan my `Model` to find the correct `ModelMetadata` for each property that I want to display. But I am not able to render the properties using `Html.DisplayFor` correctly.

I tried to display my property like so

```
// First I find the ModelMetadata for the property
// I call this statement in a loop and each iteration I pass a different PropertyName to get the correct model
ModelMetadata columnMetadata = elementsMetadata.First(x => x.PropertyName == column.PropertyName);

// I attempted to render the columnMetadata object like so
Html.DisplayFor(x => columnMetadata.Model)
```

The above code works "in term of displaying the correct value" However it does not use the correct `DisplayTemplate` which is causing the incorrect format.

For example I have an editor template called `Currency.cshtml` which simply display `Model.ToString("C")`. I also have another display template called `Status.cshtml` which accepts boolean value and return "Active" or "Inactive". Both display-template are located in `~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates`.

But for some reason `Html.DisplayFor()` isn't looking for the proper `template`. Here is an example of one of my view-models

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public decimal Rate { get; set; }

    [DataType("Status"), DisplayName("Status")]
    public bool Active { get; set; }
}
```

Currently my view shows a disabled checkbox for the `Active` property and a non-formatted number for my `Rate` property.

How can I correctly display `ModelMetadata` object where the correct display-template is used based on the property data-type?

Comment: `ModelMetadata` contains a `DataTypeName` property which should give you the value of `DataType` (and you could use that in the 2nd argument of `DisplayFor()`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke that worked! As always your awesome. But is this the right way to display the property or is there a better method to use?

Comment: I take it this is related to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51677304/how-can-i-get-the-metadata-of-the-items-in-a-collection-in-razor-view-engine), where your want just one view with `@model object`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes. I got everything to work except for 2. The proper way to display the `ModelMetadata` object. And how to correctly use `IMetadataAware` to add values to the `AdditionalValues` to the property which is decorated with the attribute that implements the `IMetadataAware`

Comment: Only just seen that comment on my other answer. Not sure what you may have done wrong, but I'll give you are more detailed example of how it works a bit later (will ping you in that answer).

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thank you so much. When time permits, please post an answer here also and I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: As for _is it the right way_? Well it works :) (and you can also use `[UIHint]` attributes - e.g. `[UIHint("Status")]public bool Active { get; set; }`), but as I noted in the previous question, using a custom `HtmlHelper` method would be better and give more flexibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ModelMetadata` contains a `DataTypeName` property, which contains the value generated by the `DataTypeAttribute`, which will be "Currency" for your `Rate` property and "Status" for you `Status` property. You can use this value in the 2nd argument of `DisplayFor()`

```
ModelMetadata columnMetadata = elementsMetadata.First(x => x.PropertyName == column.PropertyName);
string template = columnMetadata.DataTypeName;
Html.DisplayFor(x => columnMetadata.Model, template)
```

Note also that you can use the `UIHintAttribute` which also sets the value of `DataTypeName`, for example

```
[Display(Name = "Status")] // use this rather that [DisplayName]
[UIHint("Status")]
public bool Active { get; set; }
```